# Tuples conversion into JSON with python

Tags: python, json, pandas, d3.js, data-science

I would like some help converting a tuple in format `[(X, Y, Z),(..)` of type  `(string, string, int)]`  to a JSON file in the format:

```
{
    "name": "X",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Y",
        "value": Z
    }]
}
```

I have at least 1M values to convert and at the moment I have attempted using a key for the dictionary:

```
b = (dict(zip(keys,row)) for row in tuples)
```

using the JSON library

```
print (json.dumps(list(b)))
```

however this yields a JSON in the format

```
[{"type": "y", "name": "z", "count": z},...
```

Preferably I would like the Y and Z values to be nested under children and the X value to be used once per unique string.

```
   {
    "name": "X",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Y",
        "value": Z
    },
                {
        "name": "Y2",
        "value": Z2
    }]
   }
```

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JSON.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate the object `{"name": "Y", "value": Z}`?

Comment: Please explain how to get from your input data to your expected output!

Comment: I've fixed your JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a list of dicts as the output of the json with each dict be the form in your question:

The following one liner will put it into the data structure your looking for with each tuple generating it's own complete structure:

```
[{'name':i[0], 'children': [{'name': i[1], 'value': i[2]}]}  for i in tuples]
```

But I suspect you want the outer name to be unique with inner children being built from multiple tuples, such that there is only one such structure generated with `'name' == X`.

To do it in a memory efficient manner start by sorting your tuples by X:

```
# should work as long as you aren't doing any fancy sorting
stuples = sorted(tuples) 

name = None
dat = None
for t in stuples:
    if name != t[0]:
        if dat is not None:
            writeDat(json.dumps(dat))
        name = t[0]
        dat = {'name': t[0], 'children': [{'name': t[1], 'value': t[2]}]}
    else:
        dat['children'].append({'name': t1, 'value': t[2]})
```

I assume you have a function to write one of these out such as `writeDat()` that takes the json so you aren't storing them all in ram.

Comment: This worked absolutely perfect. Thanks

Comment: If it answers your question, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json 
list_of_tuples = [('jack', 'jill', 5), ('baba','black', 6)]
result = list()
for each_tuple in list_of_tuples:
    temp = dict()
    temp['name'] = each_tuple[0]
    temp['children'] = [{'name': each_tuple[1],'value':each_tuple[2]}]
    result.append(temp)

json.dumps(result)
```

Updated.

Comment: `NameError: name 'v' is not defined`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json

ts = [("egg", "bacon", 1), ("egg", "sausage", 2), ("spam", "baked beans", 3)]
for t in ts:
    o = {"name": t[0], "children": [{"name": t[1], "value": t[2]}]}
    j = json.dumps(o)
    print(j)
```

Output:

```
{"children": [{"name": "bacon", "value": 1}], "name": "egg"}
{"children": [{"name": "sausage", "value": 2}], "name": "egg"}
{"children": [{"name": "baked beans", "value": 3}], "name": "spam"}
```

Comment: This one gives me the desired output, however I have one followup question. If I wanted the JSON output to have  ("egg", "sausage", 2), ("spam", "baked beans", 3) as tuples inside the children tree. with just name and children listed once. How do you suggest i proceed

Comment: Please edit your question or create a new one.

Comment: edited the question as requested

Comment: With the answers already given you should be able to solve the rest for yourself.